# MS Access Report RecordSource is a query with a parameter. How do I pass a parameter value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a form named testForm with a text box named txtUnitID, and a button cmdOpenTestReport.
The code for the button is:

```
Private Sub cmdOpenTestReport_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport reportname:="testReport", view:=acViewPreview
End Sub
```

The Record Source of testReport is

```
SELECT * from tblTest WHERE UnitID = [txtUnitID]
```

I also have a Text Box in my report called txtUnitID where I want the value of testForm!txtUnitID

How do I pass the value of testForm!txtUnitID to the Record Source query of testReport and also to testReport!txtUnitID?

I have tried setting the value of Me.txtUnitID like this:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.txtUnitID = 1
End Sub
```

But I think this doesn't work because the report is not open at that point.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the TextBox on your form from wherever (RecordSource of report or VBA code):

```
Forms!testForm!txtUnitID
```